# Access to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have my Google Drive set up on my organization's laptop. Does my company have access to or the ability to view the files I have on my Google Drive?
If yes, how can I keep it on my laptop and yet restrict their access?

Comment: Don't mix business with pleasure. If they want the laptop back, do you have sufficient authority to wipe it first? if not, don't do it.

Comment: I don't know if I might need any authority to delete the info, that's why I asked this question about the function and access to Google Drive. When I asked my question, I didn't mention using Google Drive for fun or anything like that. I'm just wondering how you got the idea that I might be mixing business and pleasure.

Comment: It's the way you worded your question - "my Google Drive set up on my organization's laptop"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have or plan to have files you don't want the company to access, don't add them to folders synced using an account managed by the Company.

Your company can access the files in My Drive of accounts that the company manages and Share Drives created by accounts that the company governs. Still, they can't access files in My Drive of accounts managed by other companies or from consumer accounts i.e. using an email address with gmail.com domain.

For details about how to use Google Drive for Desktop, check out [Use Google Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124?).

Answer (score 2):

The company's laptop is the company's property.  They have legitimate access to each and every file you put on there (possibly by simply taking the laptop from you and copying them).  You generally don't have the right to restrict their access, because it isn't your laptop, it's the company's.

This also goes for any files you access via the web using the company's laptop, even if you didn't "download" them.  Technically speaking, having ongoing access could be harder but certainly not impossible if they were determined to do so.

The best way to restrict the company from accessing the files is to never put them on the laptop, and stop accessing personal files using the company's equipment.